# Ошибка при выполнении функции

Tags: c++, c, ряды, borland

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<conio.h>                  
#include<math.h>

void main()                
{ 
  int i, n, x;                
  float s = 0, r;                
  clrscr();                                       
  printf("Vvedite n");   
  scanf("%d", &n);             
  printf("Vvedite x");    
  scanf("%d", &x);        
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)        
  {
    r = pow(x, i)/(2 * i); 
    s += r;   
  }
  printf ("Summa S=%3.7f\n", s);
  getch();   
}
```

Нужно вычислить сумму числового ряда. После всего этого выдаёт ошибку с надписью: "`Thread Stopped E:\main.exe. Fault: floating point overflow a 0x0`". Я уже в отчаянии, не могу понять в чём дело. Есть подозрения на саму программу, но с другими кодами всё работает

Comment: а при каких именно значениях ваша программа падает, вы предлагаете догадаться?

Comment: @Treaq, для больших значений `x` и `n` так и должно быть.

Comment: Неужели 1 или 2 это уже большие числа?

Comment: @Treaq, при 1 и 2 (и даже 10 и 20) у меня (правда, не borland, а MinGW) она работает, а вот при 100 и 200 возникает переполнение.

Смените компилятор (а лучше уйдите с винды в \*nix).

Answer (score 2):

Не пользуйтесь функцией `pow`. Примените рекуррентное соотношение, как вам наверняка и рассказывал преподаватель.

---

Кстати, ваш ряд сходится только для `x` в промежутке `[-1, 1)`, так что задавать другие значения `x` ни имеет (математического) смысла.

---

А вообще-то, `d/dx \sum_{i=1} x^i/(2i) = 1/2 \sum_{i=1} x^{i-1} = 1/2 \sum_{i=0} x^i = 1/(2*(x-1))`, поэтому `\sum_{i=1} x^i/(2i) = 1/2 \int dx/(x-1) = ln |x-1|`.

*Обновление*

Попробуйте так:

```
r = x / 2.0; // в начале

s += r;
r *= (x * i) / (i + 1); // подготовка следующего члена ряда в цикле
```

(Порядок важен!)

Comment: Как раз таки не рассказывал, мы самоучки почти. Но спасибо больше, жаль наградить не могу(